# R: Resample raster layer according to a polygon grid

Tags: raster, r, polygon, resampling

I have a reference polygon grid and several raster layers with varying resolutions. I need to resample raster payers so that the cell sizes and locations of the new rasters match the cell sizes and shapes in the polygon layer.

For example, if I have the following sample data

```
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f) 
plot(r)
```

[image]

I need to resample it so that it aligns with the polygon grid below, meaning that in the new raster each cell is equal to a rectangle in the polygonal layer

```
g <- st_make_grid(r,n=50)
plot(r)
plot(g,add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the polygon grid as a layer to extract values from the raster layers? This would avoid having to try reposition and resample the raster layers.

Comment: That is an excellent idea, I can indeed just do that. Thx!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it. - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the polygon grid layer as a layer to extract values from the raster layers. Doing it this way would also avoid having to try reposition and resample the raster layers.